# Model field value always null - EF5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I have an integer that is set in my DB but it is always null when running, whether in a view or controller.
Here is my code:

```
@if(Model.DefaultTerrain == null)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do other thing
}
```

The app reads the correct database.
DefaultTerrain is a nullable integer in the Project table, it shows in the edmx file.
Other fields are OK.
This is not a coding issue, rather a configuration issue I believe (this code works in production; I checked out the project from a repo and am now testing on my local machine for improvements).

EF5, IIS 8

Thanks

Comment: Show the code from where you set the model value.

Comment: @Mairaj if you mean the Model instance it is 'Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);' where db is an instance of my db; If you mean the field value, there is no such code since I am using Entity Framework.

Comment: Do your return whole object `project` or a single property ?

Comment: @Mairaj db.Projects.Find(id) returns whole object project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS using the edmx file, I refreshed the Project table from the database then re-published the app and that fixed it.